# Node is not in primary or recovering state upon removal of instance from replication set

Tags: django, mongodb

I currently have 4 mongo instances in a replication set, one of them is obsolete and needs to be removed, but when I run `rs.remove("hostname")` my django application instantly starts throwing `Node is not in primary or recovering state upon removal of instance from replication set` until I add the instance back in.

This is my `rs.status()`

```
    rs_pimapi:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs_pimapi",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:05.607Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(-1),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1501205225, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : Timestamp(1501205225, 1),
                "durableOpTime" : Timestamp(1501205222, 1)
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 25,
                        "name" : "10.231.158.108:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 7212131,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1501205225, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:05Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1500629818, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2017-07-21T09:36:58Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 278273,
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 29,
                        "name" : "10.0.1.95:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 20216,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1501205222, 1),
                        "optimeDurable" : Timestamp(1501205222, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:02Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:02Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:04.286Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:04.373Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
                        "syncingTo" : "10.231.158.108:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 278273
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 30,
                        "name" : "10.0.0.213:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 14382,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1501205222, 1),
                        "optimeDurable" : Timestamp(1501205222, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:02Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:02Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:04.380Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:04.401Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
                        "syncingTo" : "10.0.1.95:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 278273
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 31,
                        "name" : "10.124.225.51:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 6595,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1501205222, 1),
                        "optimeDurable" : Timestamp(1501205222, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:02Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:02Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:03.679Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-07-28T01:27:03.716Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "syncingTo" : "10.0.0.213:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 278273
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

And `rs.config()`

```
{
        "_id" : "rs_pimapi",
        "version" : 278273,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 25,
                        "host" : "10.231.158.108:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 29,
                        "host" : "10.0.1.95:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 0.5,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 30,
                        "host" : "10.0.0.213:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 31,
                        "host" : "10.124.225.51:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : 2000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                }
        }
}
```

And in my django settings I have set the replica set as
`REPLICA_HOSTS = 'mongodb://10.231.158.108,10.0.1.95,10.0.0.51'`

The problem appears when I try to remove `10.124.225.51` which, isn't referenced in the config, and from my understanding of replication sets, should be able to be taken out safely.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution for this? Im on the same situation and totally stuck. Thanks.